# glow around div with border and color

Tags: css, html

Is there any way to add a glow around the div? Look at twitter login and how there is a blue glow around the input box, can that be done for the div?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the complete code to style a div exactly like the twitter login input. The styles for the blue border are the `box-shadow` and `border` styles for the selector `div[contenteditable]:focus`. **[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/IlUdikiQ/1/edit)**

**Markup:**

```
<div contenteditable="true">Username or email</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div[contenteditable]:focus {
  border: 1px solid rgb(86, 180, 239);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset, 0px 0px 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
}

div[contenteditable] {
  width: 97%;
  max-width: 280px;
  margin-right: 10px;

  font-family: Arial,sans-serif;

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.05),0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.05),0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.075);

  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;

  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 34):

**CSS3** can do that

```
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px blue; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px blue; 
box-shadow:0 0 20px blue;
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kw5Ys/).

Comment: Ah, okay. Well... let me see if I can set a JSFiddle for you. It works for me.

Comment: What browser doesn't it show for you?  Here's an example. http://jsfiddle.net/ryancowles/zs7XN/

Comment: Look at twitter login, you know the blue border comes around the textbox when you click on it, I want to be around the div.

Comment: Can you specify exactly which div?

Comment: This saved my day after I struggled on how to programmatically focus a button where I had no luck but instead resorted to this answer! Great answer here @ElliotBonneville!

Comment: sometimes simple is the best

Answer (score 3):

As shown before, use css: `focus`, `border` and `box-shadow`.

If using IE, make sure `<doctype>` is specified.

```
.text:focus {
    border: 1px solid #07c;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #07c;
}
```

[jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/5TwW8/)

Comment: really really good answer - so simple but with a slight color tweak it looks real pro - thanks so much man - deserves more upvotes +1

Answer (score 1):

Also you will face some problem with Internet Explorer while dealing this issue. IE-9 How ever supports box-shadow but the previous versions don't, Check it out [here](http://ole-laursen.blogspot.in/2009/08/using-css3-box-shadow-with-ie.html) for making it work in all versions of IE